# how to disable client caching on ruby on rails application

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i've a problem with my ruby on rails application.
My web application save http response data in cache so if the client browser view too much page 
the client cache fill the ram memory of the client machine!!! it's a problem because my 
application show photo, so any page is about 17KB and it's a problem for the client, 
expecially if that is a mobile device!!!!

how can i disable client cache?

Comment: Normally, you as a web developer shouldn't have to worry about browser cache taking too much RAM. Do you have any complex JavaScripts or the like that may cause excessive memory use?

Comment: yes...my application show sequence of photo taked by IPCam.
There is a javascript function that reload the image on the page (and other data, like the created_at information).
So after showing 40-50 a mobile client (table or smartphone) is out of ram!!!!

Comment: Make sure not to hold references to the images in your javascript code. If the image is just displayed in an <img> tag, the browser should manage its cache properly.

Answer (score 0):

i need to manipulate img with javascript.
Now the system is like this:

in the first page there is the tag img for the first image:

```
   <img id="photo" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%= @data %>" alt="photo">
```

in the same page there is this javascript code;
        setInterval(update,1000)

```
     function update(){
         $.ajax({
            url: "LINK TO THE NEXT PHOTO"})
         });
      }
```

The ajax request caller a method that returns the new code's photo:

```
    ' $("#photo").attr('src', "data:image/jpeg;base64,<%= @data %>")
```